# Refactoring Rails Routes to still pass testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, refactoring

I can't get this to pass:

```
  %w[home help about contact].each do |page|
    get :controller => 'static_pages', :action => page
  end
```

I was trying to refactor this code:

```
  get 'static_pages/home'
  get 'static_pages/help'
  get 'static_pages/about'
  get 'static_pages/contact'
```

Please help.

Comment: Looks like you're doing The Rails Tutorial.  Got a github repo that people can have a look at?

Comment: Yes I am. I've pushed it to https://github.com/sajeev86/sample_app - I've commented out the refactor attempt in config/routes.rb (Also I might add that its not part of the tutorial to refactor this part of the code. I'm just doing it for fun!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static_pages = %w(home help about contact).map {|p| p.to_sym}

resources :static_pages, only: static_pages do
  static_pages.each do |page|
    get page, on: :collection
  end
end
```

render

```
$ rake routes
   home_static_pages GET /static_pages/home(.:format)       static_pages#home
   help_static_pages GET /static_pages/help(.:format)       static_pages#help
   about_static_pages GET /static_pages/about(.:format)     static_pages#about
   contact_static_pages GET /static_pages/contact(.:format) static_pages#contact
```

use `only: static_pages` to not generate CRUD routes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you don't like the [original code](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed/blob/master/config/routes.rb) of:

```
root to: 'static_pages#home'

match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
```

and you want to get the same routes, you could go with a simple loop like:

```
root to: 'static_pages#home'

%w(help about contact).each do |page|
   get "#{page}" => "static_pages##{page}"
end
```

Though, to me this doesn't really seem like enough of a refactor to justify it.

#### Edit

To fix the errors on your code, use:

```
%w(home help about contact).each do |page|
  get "/#{page}", :controller => 'static_pages', :action => page
end
```

Check the [api for `match`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base.html#method-i-match) for valid arguments to `get`.

Comment: I've run both through but they don't pass.

Comment: Sorry I should have shown my test code. `visit '/static_pages/about'` When I edit your edited with this `match "/static_pages/#{page}", :controller => 'static_pages', :action => page` it passes! Thanks for your help.